# How validator re-join is prevented?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0

According to [this article](https://medium.com/chainsafe-systems/8-things-every-eth2-validator-should-know-before-staking-94df41701487), once a validator performs a voluntary exit, he can not rejoin:

> If you’ve performed a voluntary exit, or been slashed, you won’t be able to rejoin. This means if you want to be a validator again, it’ll require an additional 32 ETH deposit and a new validator account.

How is this possible? If this is true, it would either make the withdrawn ETH "tainted" and non-fungible (creating a whole new market), or it would be very easy to circumvent, allowing for "laundering" the withdrawn ETH to be re-staked.

Answer (score 0):

The full specifications for 2.0 are far from ready yet. We are currently living in a transitory phase where not all of the rules are the same as they will be when 2.0 is fully ready.

Currently it is impossible to get your staked Eth back, no matter how you exit. You may exit but the Eth will be stuck, as there is no functionality to withdraw the stake.

I'm not sure how final the specification you quoted is, but my guess is that it will change for the final version - I don't see any reason to "taint" the Eth in some way as the (possible) punishment has already been dealt: slashing of the stake.

So, summa summarum, my guess is that in the future it is possible to rejoin as a staker with the same Eth (and possibly also from the same address).